# Determine all k ∈ N such that $n^{k}$ ≡ n (mod 7) for all integers n.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How would I prove this statement?
This is what I have tried, but it seems to be incorrect:

- writing the congruence as 7 | n(1-$n^{k-1}$)
- then, either 7 | n or 7 | 1-$n^{k-1}$, none of which cannot be true for all n regardless of the k value

I'm not sure where I went wrong, are there any other approaches I should try?

Comment: Your second bullet point is either a typo or a misstep in logic.

Comment: Specialize $\,n=7\,$ in the Theorem in the linked dupe.

Comment: Why not just try small $k$ to see if you find a pattern?  Certainly you only need to try $7$ values for $n$.